# Not able to return value for .Queue("fx").length

Tags: jquery, raphael, jquery-animate

when I try to call

```
 paper.queue("fx").length
```

I get object not supported error. May i know how to call .queue("fx").length. Can I use it in a div which has more than a single DOM. I am trying to step my animation one by one.

```
 <div  id="Paper"></div>

 paper = Raphael('Paper', paperWidth, paperHeight);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have jquery version 1.7.1 or latest for `.queue`

Try -

```
$('#Paper').queue("fx").length
```

Read more on queue - http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: I thought I tried this. It returns 0. I guess your answer works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess.

If you're binding your event to an ID, you should put `#` in front of it.

```
   paper = Raphael('#Paper', paperWidth, paperHeight);
```

Let me know how that works out.

Comment: No.. It did not work. Actually if I add the # then I could not draw the shapes in the paper.Thanks though

Comment: Well then try 2 other things.. 1st, use `length();` instead of `length`  or, maybe it's `Queue` instead of `queue` ?